# show textures - maya to three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, maya

i need converted maya to js for simple model with textures
work fine but show without textures
my code:
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

```
loader.load( "models/t2.js", function(geometry) {
var part1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial() );
    mesh =new THREE.Object3D();
    mesh.add( part1 );
    //var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.position.set(0,0,0);
    mesh.rotation.set(0,0,0);
    mesh.scale.set(30,30,30);
    scene.add( mesh );
});
```

online demo : http://mika.ir/virtual-exhibition/
download code : http://mika.ir/virtual-exhibition/virtual-exhibition.rar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass in a texture to one of the material objects. Use either MeshLambertMaterial or MeshPhongMaterial and pass in a THREE.Texture. You first have to load the texture and pass a callback. I would do something like the following if the texture you want to load is 'path/texture.png':

```
var modelTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('path/texture.png', false, loadModel);

function loadModel() {
    loader.load( "models/t2.js", function(geometry) {
    var part1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: modelTexture });
        mesh =new THREE.Object3D();
        mesh.add( part1 );
        //var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        mesh.position.set(0,0,0);
        mesh.rotation.set(0,0,0);
        mesh.scale.set(30,30,30);
        scene.add( mesh );
    });
}
```

Comment: i need load textures from js file